# How to plot a function in matplotlib when getting the following error:ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the function I am trying to plot

```
def f(x):
    return 50 * (1 / (1 + ((50/5)-1) * e ** -max(0, 0.1 * x)))
```

I am getting the following error when trying to plot it using matplotlib:
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I believe it is because of the `-max(0, 0.1 * x)` part of my function.

Here is the full version of my matplotlib code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import e

# 100 linearly spaced numbers between -10 and 100
x = np.linspace(-10,100,200)

def f(x):
    return 50 * (1 / (1 + ((50/5)-1) * e ** -max(0, 0.1 * x)))

# setting the axes at the centre
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

# plot the function
plt.plot(x,f(x), 'r')

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

Researching [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous) error leads me to find out that while the `max()` function normally evaluates numbers, due to it being passed x which is a `np.linspace()` and not a number then it is unable to evaluate it.

How can I plot the `f(x)` function without changing it internally (as this would ruin some unit tests that I have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reread your question, and you want to know if the function can be run as-is without modification, and the answer is yes. You need to evaluate it point-by-point with the current design.

I do this by creating a `zeros` array of the length of numbers that you want to evaluate, and insert the function values into each index. The result is similar to the previous answer.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import e

# 100 linearly spaced numbers between -10 and 100
N=200
x = np.linspace(-10,100,N)

def f(x):
    return 50 * (1 / (1 + ((50/5)-1) * e ** -max(0, 0.1 * x)))

f_eval = np.zeros(N)
for idx, i in enumerate(x):
    f_eval[idx] = f(i)


# setting the axes at the centre
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

# plot the function
plt.plot(x,f_eval, 'r')

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image: result]